# How to differentiate two HTML elements with same tagname and same text

Tags: html, html-parsing, jsoup

I would like to know is there any method in Jsoup that tells me an element with same tag name, text and class (if any) is different from other element with same tag name, text and same class (if any). For clarification consider the following HTML snippet :

```
<html>
<body>
<div>Here I Am</div><div>First Time</div>
<div>Here I Am</div><div>Again</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now in the above code how can I separate the two elements with div tag and text **Here I am**. Also note that here the two elements have no id.

The above example is very simple but actual scenario may be more complex. So if you kindly suggest me a generalized answer I will be really grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Give id for making it unique for the document. this can be done as

```
<div id="first">Here I Am</div>
<div id="second">Here I Am</div>
```

Comment: I know by id it can be differentiated, but I have not created the page , i am just parsing the page. So I want to know is there any other way by which they can be differentiated.

Comment: Yes I though hashCode will differentiate them but saw two different element giving same hash code. I have not any other idea.

Comment: I have also tried to do this by accessing the text associated with the next element. But could not understand how to do that in Jsoup.

Answer (score 1):

Under the concept of DOM and XPath, these nodes are the same EXCEPT its canonical order. If you want to access the n-th node of this pattern,

```
//div[text()='Here I Am'][n]
```

where *n* is 0-based.

Comment: So you mean index i.e. the canonical order is the only way to separate them?

Comment: There are diffrent only by index, so there is no other way!

Answer (score 1):

Get all div elements and select what you want.

**Example**

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<html>\n" +
        "<body>\n" +
        "<div>Here I Am</div><div>First Time</div>\n" +
        "<div>Here I Am</div><div>Again</div>\n" +
        "</body>\n" +
        "</html>");

Element div = doc.select("div").first();

System.out.println(div.html());
```

**Output**

```
Here I Am
```

Other elements are accessible by index.

**Example**

```
Element div = doc.select("div").get(3);
```

**Output**:

```
Again
```

Answer (score 0):

You could identify the divs. For example, you could do this:

```
<div class="div1"><h2>Here I Am</h2></div>

     <div class="div2"><h2>First Time</h2></div>

<div class="div3"><h2>Here I Am</h2></div>

     <div class="div4"><h2>Again</h2></div>
```

Comment: I know by id they can be differentiated, but I have not created the page , i am just parsing the page. So I want to know is there any other way other than by id, by which they can be differentiated.

Comment: You could also use classes like I have above if you want. The main difference for this is that you can use the same class for multiple things

Comment: But in the above code snippet if the classes of the two elements are same then how can you differentiate them?

Comment: Make them different classes as I have shown. This way, in the future, it's possible to use the same class for a different element if you really want to